# WaitForSeconds Gradually become out of Sync... Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, wait, frame-rate

I am creating a rythm VR game for google cardboard, inspired by **Beat** **Saber** on PSVR and Oculus Rift.

---

The concept is that blocks with different directions come at you, following the rythm of the music, just like in **Beat** **Saber**.
For every music I have created a **ScriptableObject** called music, with every parameter it should contain like the difficulty of the song, the name, etc. but also an array of Vector3 called notes : the first float of the Vector corresponds to the time the note should be beaten in the rythm of the music starting from 0: [ScriptableObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THGJg.png)

Then in a script called *SlashSpawnManagement*, where every thing is based on WaitForSeconds(), I spawn the blocks to smash. It's realy hard for me to explain wih words the order I do it in, so here is an image : [Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR26v.png)

In theory, what this script does, it waits for some time, spawns a block, waits for some time, spawn a block, etc. The logic seems okay, but here's the **weird part**. As you play the song the distance between each block gradually becomes bigger and bigger, meaning the blocks become more and more out of sync with the music. It starts very well, but at the end of the music there is at least a 5s gap.

---

I figured it has something to do with the frame rate drop, so I tried to set the frameRate to something low with :

```
QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;  // VSync must be disabled
Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
```

But it doesn't solve the problem. I tried with **WaitForSecondsRealtime** instead of **WaitForSeconds**, but nothing changes. I have read somewhere that WaitForSeconds depends on the frame rate... Where I calculated the time, I tried sustractng h divided by a number to even out the gradual gap. This works for some blocks but not every block: `Notes[j][0] - h / 500`

---

So here's my question, how do I make the WaitForSeconds, or any other method consistent with the seconds provided ?

Thank you In advance,

PS : For more clarifications, please ask and please forgive my typos and my english :)

Comment: If you're doing anything with rhythmic sound, it is essential to use the audio to drive the timing of everything. I'm not sure how this might be achieved in unity, but using any timing mechanism other than the audio will result in loss of sync. The timing of your sound output should run the show. The audio clock does not keep in sync with any threading timers/ screen timers.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSettings-dspTime.html is the one-true source of time when it comes to audio.

Comment: @spender Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to use WaitForSeconds the timing of audio and hope for the best is hoping a big hope.

Have a list of Vector3s prepared in advance. If you want to prepare the list using the rythm - it will work. Use AudioSource's time to check every Update whether the timing is right and spawn a block at that moment.

```
void Update () {
    SpawnIfTimingIsRight();
}

void SpawnIfTimingIsRight() {
    float nextTiming = timingsArray[nextIndex].x;
    // Time For Block To Get To Position
    float blockTime = this.blockDistanceToTravel / this.blockSpeed;
    float timeToSpawnBlock = nextTiming - blockTime;
    if (this.audioSource.time >= nextTiming && (this.audioSource.time - Time.deltaTime) < nextTiming) {
        // Spawn block
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure thing, friend.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something to happen in regular time intervals, it is important to make sure that errors don't accumulate.

Don't:

```
private IEnumerable DoInIntervals()
{
    while (this)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); // this will NOT wait exactly 1 second but a few ms more. This error accumulates over time
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Do:

```
private IEnumerable DoInIntervals()
{
    const float interval = 1f;
    float nextEventTime = Time.time + interval;

    while (this)
    {
        if (Time.time >= nextEventTime)
        {
            nextEventTime += interval; // this ensures that nextEventTime is exactly (interval) seconds after the previous nextEventTime. Errors are not accumulated.
            DoSomething();
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This will make sure your events happen in regular intervals.

Note: Even though this will be regular, it does not guarantee that it will stay in sync with other systems like audio. That can only be achieved by having a shared time between systems, like spender mentioned in his comment on your question.

Comment: this is very much along the lines of my thinking. While dsp clock might drift against  Time.time a little bit, it should be hardly measurable after few minutes